# How to check only 1 element in a tuple Python

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of tuples:

```
l = []
```

In the tuple:

```
a = (0, 1, 1)
l.append(a)
```

I want to check if there exists value "1" on the second position but not the third.

Comment: Do you mean `a[1] == 1`?

Comment: No sorry, explained it wrong

Comment: @Paul, then _quickly_ edit your question or you'll lose lots of rep.

Comment: Well this is an example of not writing the full question, getting a lots of answers then changing the requirements :|

Comment: ...and losing all the reputation gained by hard work.

Comment: confusing question as well.  l = []  , where [] is NOT a tuple but a list. Then he put tuple into the list. then ..... the question is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

Checking 1 exists in position 2:

```
>>> a = (0, 1, 1)
>>> if a[1] == 1:
...  print("yes it is")
...
yes it is
```

If you are checking to make sure that 1 exists in position 2 and not 3:

```
>>> a = (0, 1, 1)
>>> if a[1] == 1 and a[2] != 1:
...  print('hello')
...
>>>
```

If you have a list of tuples:

```
a = [(0,1,1), (0,1,1), (0,1,0)]
```

And are looking to filter out those where the criteria holds for `a[1] == 1` and `a[2] != 1`, then collect them in a comprehension like this:

```
a = [(0,1,1), (0,1,1), (0,1,0)]
res = [v for i, v in enumerate(a) if v[1] == 1 and v[2] != 1]
print(res)
# [(0, 1, 0)]
```

Comment: You might not want to use the shell for answers because it can be difficult to copy and paste the code. Good answer though.

Comment: @MarkyPython people should not just copy and paste the provided answer. This is only my opinion

Comment: I disagree, because if they cannot copy and paste the answer they will just retype it anyway. May as well make it easier. And for me, what is helpful is to get the code into the editor so I can read through it there and see what the code is meant to do. That is my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
a = (0, 1, 1)
if a.index(1) == 1:
    #do something
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
if a[1] == 1 and a[2] != 1:
    #do something
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (a[1]==1) and (a[2]!=1):
    # do something
else:
    # the condition isn't met
```

Answer (score 0):

To find if the second value is `1` and the third value is not `1`, do this:

```
if a[1] == 1 and a[2] != 1: 
    return True # Or whatever you want to do
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if element in thetuple:
    //whatever u want
```

if you want to check for secn positions,it will run serially.

And to check the index you can do

```
thetuple.index("index")
```